# Integrate Pentaho report designer with web application project

Tags: web-applications, struts2, pentaho

I have a requirement in web application to generate few reports. This report will include images, tables etc. My web application was built on Struts 2.X framework.

I choosen Pentaho BI to generate reports. Can any one guide me how to integrate Pentaho BI OR reports in my web application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a link to Pentaho's guide on embedding.  It contains instructions for doing this.

http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Freporting_embedders_guide%2Ftopic_introduction.html